# What screw for 2.0 mm plastic hole in housing

Tags: plastic, fasteners

I'm thinking about using the [Bopla UM 32009 housing](https://www.bopla.de/en/enclosure-technology/product/ultramas/ultramas-um-309-l-enclosures/um-32009.html) for my product. It has little standoffs for attaching PCBs. These standoffs are made of plastic, and seem to be drilled (or molded?) to a diameter of 2.0 mm.

My questions: What type of screw would be appropriate for this hole diameter? A regular M2 machine screw won't work well. An M2.5 might work, but would probably deform the standoff.

An M2.2 self tapping screw might work I suppose, but I think the hole is a bit large for this (recommended is something like 1.8 mm).

Is there some kind of imperial screw that fits well into a 2.0 mm plastic hole?

Comment: If the hole is exactly 2mm diameter, M2.5 self-taping screw.

Comment: Consider e-mailing the manufacturer of you enclosure.  They should know what kind of screw the holes are intended for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typing "screws" in the search field of the Bopla website finds [this link](https://www.bopla.de/en/service/technical-information/plastic/general-information-on-plastic-enclosures/screws-and-attachments-for-plastic-enclosures.html).

It looks like the screw you need is has a shank diameter of 1.7–1.8 mm and a thread diameter of 2.2 mm. The head is rounded.